# where statement - Select List return all values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a select list depending on a AD group. My question is - how can I add a value of All to each of the 2 different SelectLists that will return only all the values of the Select List with the All value. So in the example below if the user is in the role of IntranetAdmin and all is selected it would return the values of Phone and Project if not and All is selected it would return the values of Desk and PC. Does that make sense?

SB

```
List<SelectListItem> RequestType = new List<SelectListItem>();

if (!User.IsInRole("IntranetAdmins"))
 {
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "All", Value = "" });
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Phone", Value = "Phone" });
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Project", Value = "Project" });
 }
  else
 {
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "All", Value = "" });
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Desk", Value = "Desk" });
RequestType.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "PC", Value = "PC" });

    var desk = (from m in db.Desks.OrderByDescending(m => m.ID)
where (m.RequestType == RequestType || RequestType == null || RequestType == "")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the question, plus there is no Phone in example you shared.

Comment: Maybe do it all with a bunch of if statement and when it's working look at how you can simplify it using some data structure. Seems like each Item should be linked to a list of role.